# Работа с svg и визуальный редактор

Tags: javascript

С сервера будут приходить несколько svg букв, фигур. В визуальном редакторе их нужно двигать, менять размер, цвет. Cохранить результат в png

Дайте, пожалуйста, рекомендации какая библиотека js поможет в реализации данного функционала.

Comment: Я бы в обычном canvas-е сделал. Конвертируйте SVG в пиксели и делаете с ними что хотите.